# Postgres - Find pairs of neighbours polygons

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a list of IDs (polygons) and in a table (i.e. table *zones*) I've all the possible permutations of these IDs. In another table (i.e. *zonesid*) I've their corresponding geometries  [geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)].

```
table zones:
 index | zone1  | zone2 
-------+--------+--------
     0 |    100 |    100
     1 |    100 |    101
     2 |    100 |    102
     3 |    101 |    100
     4 |    101 |    101
     5 |    101 |    102
     6 |    102 |    100
     7 |    102 |    101
     8 |    102 |    102

table zonesid:
 index | zone_id | geom 
-------+--------+--------
     0 |    100 |  geom100  
     1 |    101 |  geom101
     2 |    102 |  geom102
```

Now I'd need to find which areas are adjacent and write a 1 next to the pair.

I've read the question [Finding neighbouring polygons - postgis query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866416/finding-neighbouring-polygons-postgis-query) and I think I need something similar, even if in this case I need to make it indicating the exact pair.

In the above example let's say that just 100 and 102 are adjacent. It should be:

```
table zones:
 index | zone1  | zone2   | adiacent
-------+--------+---------+--------
     0 |    100 |    100  |    0
     1 |    100 |    101  |    0
     2 |    100 |    102  |    1
     3 |    101 |    100  |    0
     4 |    101 |    101  |    0
     5 |    101 |    102  |    0
     6 |    102 |    100  |    1
     7 |    102 |    101  |    0
     8 |    102 |    102  |    0
```

I've started with:

```
ALTER TABLE zones
ADD COLUMN adjacent bigint;

UPDATE zones set adjacent=1, time=2
  FROM (
     SELECT (*)
       FROM zonesid as a,
            zonesid as b,
            zones as c,
            zones as d
       WHERE ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom) 
       AND c.zone1 != d.zone2
     ) as subquery
 WHERE c.zone1 = subquery.zoneid
```

But... I'm struggling in getting how to refer correctly to the table zonesid to compare the pairs and then get which they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine helped me (Thanks again!). I post the answer that works for me, in case it could be useful to someone else:

```
with adjacent_pairs as (
select
a.zone_id zone_id_1,
q.zone_id zone_id_2
from zonesid a
cross join lateral (
select zone_id
from zonesid b
where
st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 0)
and a.zone_id != b.zone_id
) q
)
update zones a
set adjacent = 1
from adjacent_pairs b
where
a.zone_a = b.zone_id_1
and a.zone_b = b.zone_id_2;

update zones
set adjacent = 0
where adjacent is null;
```